# Dynamic plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, dynamic, plot

Imagine we quickly create a random matrix called 'number':

```
matrix1=rand(10);
m=0.5;

number=zeros(size(matrix1));

for i=2:9
    for j=2:9
        number1(i,j)=(matrix1(i,j+1).*m);
        number2(i,j)=(matrix1(i+1,j).*m);
        number(i,j)=sqrt((number1(i,j))^2+(number2(i,j))^2);
    end
end

imagesc(number)
```

You can see that the value of number(i,j) is dependent on m. Now i want to make a plot where m values vary in function of the day of the year.

```
mnew=zeros(365,1);

for s=1:365
    mnew(s)=m*s;
end
```

I now got number(i,j) with the values that are dependent on m, and a file with the temporal evolution of m throughout the year. How can i now plot a dynamic plot which will show the evolution of number(i,j) throughtout the year?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider turning your plot into a movie...

Documentation here:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie2avi.html